# Spring get SOAP all local names in body

Tags: spring, soap, spring-ws

I want to check if SOAP body contain some local name like `pos:searchText`. I have to use `MessageContext` because I am using `EndpointInterceptorAdapter`.

Here is my SOAP request.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
  <pos:getSearchRequest> 
     <pos:searchText>some Text</pos:searchText>
     <pos:anotherField>example</pos:anotherField>
  </pos:getSearchRequest>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And unmarshalling doesn't work because I interceptor all the request and there is no model for this.

How can I get all local names like `pos:searchText`?

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to see how you tried to "unmarshall" your SOAP request and also more details on the errors or difficulties you had doing so.
In a recent case where I could not unmarshall my SOAP message due to the abstraction of my interceptor, I had to make it a XML String and then easily found the elements I needed with a XPath expression. Maybe this will help you out too:

```
private String extractSearchText(MessageContext messageContext) throws IOException, XPathExpressionException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream soapResponseOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    messageContext.getResponse().writeTo(soapResponseOutputStream);
    InputSource soapResponseInputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(new String(soapResponseOutputStream.toByteArray())));
    return (String) xpath.evaluate("//pos:searchText", soapResponseInputSource, XPathConstants.STRING);
}
```

PS: I really can't see why you are not able to unmarshall your request. With more details, it would be easier to help you out and I would spend some effort on that since it's, definitely, the right way of doing what you need.